# Web scraping URL contains </a> end tag at the end how to remove

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

So I have this code to parse a url link from a website, but it contains and `</a>` end tag at the end of the url like this `http://www2.enekoshop.jp/shop/tadaseinikuten/</a>`

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($xml->retdata);

$item = array();

foreach($html->find('body') as $home) {
    //some other fields here
    $email1 = preg_replace('/[^\00-\255]+/u','',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 8)->children(1)->plaintext));

    $email = filter_var($email1, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $item['email'] = $email;
    } else {
        $item['email'] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Although I'm using `plaintext` to just scrape a text, it has `</a>` end tag. How can I remove it?

Comment: Ehh I'm confused, you are putting the domain into a variable called `$email` and then call `filter_var(..., FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);` on it?

Comment: If that `</a>` tag is always present, why not use the substring function ? `substr($url, 0, strlen($url) - 4);`

Comment: @Paul-Etienne That is not really solving the problem but instead the symptom.

Comment: What kind of object is $html?

Comment: @Xatenev it is actually from a library in codeigniter. I will complete the code.

Comment: @Xatenev I only know basic of filter_var, got code from w3schools.com

Comment: you can use this function str_replace("</a>","","http://www2.enekoshop.jp/shop/tadaseinikuten/</a>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just expand your `preg_replace()` pattern a little?

Old Pattern: `/[^\00-\255]+/u`

New Pattern: `~[^\00-\255]+|</a>$~u`

[Pattern & Replace Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/vGVuYq/1)

I am just changing your pattern delimiters to avoid escaping the forward slash in `</a>` and adding an "alternative" (`|` = 'or') to match `</a>` only at the end of the string using the `$` anchor.

```
$email1 = preg_replace('~[^\00-\255]+|</a>$~u','',trim($home->find('div[id="home"] div[id="mainblock"] div[class="txtblock"]', 8)->children(1)->plaintext));
```